# rc.local running JAR

Tags: linux, startup, executable-jar, rc

I want to execute two JAR files back to back 
one.jar
two.jar

I edited rc.local entries
and added

```
sleep 5
java -jar /path/to/first/one.jar
sleep 10
java -jar /path/to/second/two.jar
```

only one jar is able to run if i interchange the sequence
i.e. for above code one.jar executed with no issue

and for

```
sleep 10
java -jar /path/to/second/two.jar
sleep 5
java -jar /path/to/first/one.jar
```

two.jar runs fine

what is wrong with this..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution @

[How do I start two different Python scripts with rc.local?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39108/how-do-i-start-two-different-python-scripts-with-rc-local)

Just we need to put '&' between two commands.

```
java -jar /path/to/second/two.jar &
java -jar /path/to/first/one.jar
```